# Odp driver wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle, odp.net

I created a wpf application, added a dataset with a ODP Managed Driver connection. Queries work but I can't seem to get this one to play nice:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE lastname LIKE '%' + :lastname + '%'
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE lastname LIKE '%' || :lastname || '%'
```

The query builder throws an "Internal error, invalid pane configuration" and the query returns nothing. If I pass the wildcard in the :lastname, it works just fine but I need it to be in the query. What is the correct syntax?

```
    SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE lastname LIKE :lastname

    :lastname = '%Bob%' --Works
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it look something like this..?

```
  SELECT *
  FROM EMPLOYEE
  WHERE lastname LIKE '%Bob%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with PL-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE lastname LIKE '%' + :lastname + '%'
```

This should:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE lastname LIKE '%' || :lastname || '%'
```

But I understand if it doesn't. When you say Query Builder, I assume that we're talking VS DataSet/TableAdapter designer, right? I've seen it hiccup a lot on some PL-SQL, so try something else like:

```
SELECT *
FROM AS_PRODUCT
WHERE AS_PRODUCT.NAME LIKE CONCAT( '%', CONCAT(:lastname , '%'));
```

But you'll still get a 'invalid pane configuration'.

One thing is that some places will set up a schema for production and a schema for test that is the same design and on the same server but has a different name. So you set up your dataset w/ a certain connection string pointing to one schema and the query builder sticks that schema prefix all over your SQL in the code generated by the DataSet designer. Then you switch your connection string to production which has a different schema name by changing the text in the web.config, and all that generated SQL doesn't work. So I always push for two servers running the same schemas, names and all to avoid that problem.

I bring this up because by writing your query by hand in ADO.NET, you'll avoid both of these problems.